# Will iterator be damaged if remove() called but did nothing?

Tags: java, collections, iterator, concurrentmodification

Suppose I am iterating over some collection, then call `remove()` with absent key so that it does nothing. Will next iteration cause exception?

Comment: Have you tried it to find out?

Comment: What happens when you try it out?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, the `ConcurrentModificationException` is optional. A compliant container does not have to attempt to spot concurrent modifications *at all*.

However, most standard containers tend to do it.

I've just checked a couple of them in JDK7, and they only bump up the modification count once they have found the element.

Having said that, I would discourage you from relying on this behaviour.

Comment: If you know you're removing an absent key, you deliberately do a no-op. If you don't know, then you deliberately court a `ConcurrentModificationException`.  In both cases, you're doing something silly or wrong.